# Is using S3 Metadata Request to get ETag possible?

Tags: ios, amazon-s3, metadata

The thing is that I need to get the etag information from Amazon before I actually get the file itself.

After researching I found that the right way is using S3GetObjectMetadataRequest and later getObjectMetadata to fetch a S3GetObjectMetadataResponse object.

But when trying to create a S3GetObjectMetadataRequest with:

`S3GetObjectMetadataRequest *metadata = [[S3GetObjectMetadataRequest alloc] initWithKey:key withBucket:bucket];`

a strong warning is showed:

`incompatible Objective-C types initializing 'struct S3GetObjectRequest *', expected 'struct S3GetObjectMetadataRequest *'`

The documentation on S3GetObjectMetadataRequest is absent and I couldn't find any reference on this anywhere.

Am I overlooking this? Is there a easier way to get the ETag without having to download all the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually the right way to get metadata from the file. I couldn't get them because of a miss-configuration on my amazon permissions.

The strange thing is that the warning is still showing up, even if the S3GetObjectMetadataResponse is rightly created...